# Spring data Cassandra Application getting terminated after creating keyspace via spring configuration

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have created Spring data Cassandra CRUD application. While starting this application for first time it is getting terminated automatically with below error but it is creating KEYSPACE as per configuration in [CassandraConfig.java](https://github.com/rahul-ghadge/spring-boot-cassandra-crud/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.java) class.

When running application for second time it is working fine by referring previously created Keyspace and able to do CRUD operations smoothly.

Tried different approached still not sure what is missing.

Git repository: https://github.com/rahul-ghadge/spring-boot-cassandra-crud

**Versions:**
Spring Boot: 2.3.3.RELEASE
Cassandra : 3.11.7

```
2020-08-24 16:23:16.979  INFO 9740 --- [        s1-io-1] c.d.o.d.i.core.channel.ChannelFactory    : [s1] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V1, retrying with V4
2020-08-24 16:23:21.854  WARN 9740 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootCassandraCrudApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'superHeroRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'superHeroRepository' defined in com.arya.cassandra.repository.SuperHeroRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on SpringBootCassandraCrudApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_hero (age int, id bigint, name text, profession text, super_name text, super_powers frozen<super_powers>, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
2020-08-24 16:23:21.927  WARN 9740 --- [        s1-io-2] c.d.o.d.i.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler     : [s1|1780306540|0] Unexpected error while refreshing schema after DDL query, keeping previous version (CompletionException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Channel was force-closed)
2020-08-24 16:23:21.927  WARN 9740 --- [        s1-io-2] c.d.o.d.i.c.control.ControlConnection    : [s1] Unexpected error while refreshing schema for a SCHEMA_CHANGE event, keeping previous version (CompletionException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Channel was force-closed)
2020-08-24 16:23:23.994  WARN 9740 --- [     s0-admin-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.session.DefaultSession    : [s0] Error while closing com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.typesafe.DefaultDriverConfigLoader@1247f3f7 (RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated)
2020-08-24 16:23:26.062  INFO 9740 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-24 16:23:26.094  INFO 9740 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-24 16:23:26.105 ERROR 9740 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootCassandraCrudApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'superHeroRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'superHeroRepository' defined in com.arya.cassandra.repository.SuperHeroRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on SpringBootCassandraCrudApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_hero (age int, id bigint, name text, profession text, super_name text, super_powers frozen<super_powers>, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.arya.cassandra.SpringBootCassandraCrudApplication.main(SpringBootCassandraCrudApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'superHeroRepository' defined in com.arya.cassandra.repository.SuperHeroRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on SpringBootCassandraCrudApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_hero (age int, id bigint, name text, profession text, super_name text, super_powers frozen<super_powers>, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_hero (age int, id bigint, name text, profession text, super_name text, super_powers frozen<super_powers>, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_hero (age int, id bigint, name text, profession text, super_name text, super_powers frozen<super_powers>, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/arya/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_hero (age int, id bigint, name text, profession text, super_name text, super_powers frozen<super_powers>, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:350) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:343) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractSessionConfiguration.requireBeanOfType(AbstractSessionConfiguration.java:100) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration.getRequiredSessionFactory(AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java:215) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration.cassandraTemplate(AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java:146) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.arya.cassandra.config.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e6d0aee.CGLIB$cassandraTemplate$9(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.arya.cassandra.config.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e6d0aee$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9e88c5e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.arya.cassandra.config.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e6d0aee.cassandraTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_hero (age int, id bigint, name text, profession text, super_name text, super_powers frozen<super_powers>, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; Query timed out after PT2S; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:160) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraAccessor.translate(CassandraAccessor.java:379) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.translateException(CqlTemplate.java:718) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.queryForResultSet(CqlTemplate.java:250) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:148) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.lambda$createTables$0(CassandraPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.java:102) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.createTables(CassandraPersistentEntitySchemaCreator.java:102) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SessionFactoryFactoryBean.performSchemaActions(SessionFactoryFactoryBean.java:220) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SessionFactoryFactoryBean.createTables(SessionFactoryFactoryBean.java:199) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SessionFactoryFactoryBean.performSchemaAction(SessionFactoryFactoryBean.java:185) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SessionFactoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SessionFactoryFactoryBean.java:135) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:53) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:169) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Kindly please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: key logs are missing that tells whether app is connected to the cluster contact points. Can you share the full logs ?

Comment: @Barath App is connecting to Cassandra, I can see **KEYSPACE** is getting created via Configuration class.

Comment: Regardless of the examples folks may post around the internet, I do not recommend schema changes in application code.  That includes building keyspaces.  I've seen so many people try it, and encounter issues with schema sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downgrading `spring-boot-starter-parent` version to `2.2.7.RELEASE` it started working without terminating application, also creating **KEYSPACE** and **TABLES** in one go.
*Commented `getLocalDataCenter()` method from Cassandra config class, it was not there in `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` class*.

```
Spring Boot: 2.3.3.RELEASE (Not working as expected)  
Cassandra : 3.11.7  
Cassandra : 3.0.21  

Spring Boot: 2.2.9.RELEASE (Not working as expected)  
Cassandra : 3.11.7  
Cassandra : 3.0.21  

Spring Boot: 2.2.7.RELEASE (Working as expected)  
Cassandra : 3.11.7  
Cassandra : 3.0.21
```

Working code is pushed to new branch.
Git repository: https://github.com/rahul-ghadge/spring-boot-cassandra-crud/tree/working-2.2.7-bug-fix

Need to check in official documentation, what has changed after 2.2.7.RELEASE.